# SonarQube Service Starts, Runs and then Stops?

Tags: windows-services, sonarqube, windows-server-2012-r2, sonarqube-ops

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server and I managed to install the SonarQube 5.4 server as a Windows Service. I also set up a user so the service can actually start without the infamous "It started then stopped" error a lot of people seem to get. Before installing the server as a windows service, I checked that it worked using `StartSonar.bat` and it did work just fine, so I was confident when I made it into a service.

But when I try to access http://localhost:9000 there is nothing there, and it appears that shortly after starting the service it stops without any message at all. I can't tell if this is because I try to access the site (which gives me `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`in Google Chrome) or if it just closes down after a short while.

Anyone got any insight?

Comment: What do logs say ? `<sonar_install_dir>/logs/sonar.log`

Comment: Oh of course. I knew I forgot something. The sqljdbc_auth.dll file. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a beginner. I came across the same issue and fixed it.

**Ensure that the database is running.**

My log file (located at `sonarqube_home_dir/logs/sonar.log`) included the following statement.

> `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-176]`

Since I'm using the default database, I commented below lines

```
#sonar.jdbc.username=***
#sonar.jdbc.password=***
```

at `sonarqube_home_dir/conf/sonar.properties`.

Comment: I gave you an up vote, because your answer gave me a clue I need to fix my issue.  I forgot to enable the "Can Login" for the user under PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks @BlackFrog.

Answer (score 0):

This must happen due to many reasons like connection problems, permission problems so First, you have to see the logs. **/sonarqube-7.6/logs$ tailf sonar.log**. then you can find the reason. Once I had the same problem so I did like that. my error is something **Directory does not exist: lib/jdbc/mysql
org.sonar.process.MessageException: Directory does not exist: lib/jdbc/mysql** reason is I uninstall MySQL and remove all folders name contains "MySQL".

Answer (score -4):

just check whether port 9001 already in used, stop it if already in used.

Comment: The OP references port 9000, so is 9001 what you really mean? How does this help the OmniOwl, how can they check the port, what if there is something there and it is their service - stopping it probably wouldn't help resolve the problem

Comment: 9000 is default port, if your sonar is running on different port like 9001 whatever port no you assigned in "sonar.properties" file #sonar.web.port=9000.

check the log file in your rootdirectory/sonarqube-6.7\logs and open the file "sonar" and "es" to ensure that exact error.